# Placing HTML/CSS without moving other elements

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to put a live chat button on the right side of a menu without moving the menu at all.. if i put it inside of the menu then the menu will try and use it as an item and if i put it above it will move the menu down, if i put it below it will not align it correctly even if i use padding.

Can anyone tell me how to move around an element on a page freely without affecting other elements around it (i.e moving them)

CSS

```css
/*===== header =====*/ 
#header .row-1 { height:110px; background:#0d0d0d; } 
#header .row-1 .logo { position:relative; margin-right: 55px; padding:0px 0 0 0; float:left; } 
#header .nav { float:right; } 
#header .nav li { } 
#header .nav li a { color:#727171; text-decoration:none; } 
#header .nav li a:hover, 
#header .nav li a.current { color:#fff; }
```

Comment: can u give a snippet of your code?

Comment: i should know about the css of the page to answer

Comment: Here's the navigation menu CSS;

Comment: /*===== header =====*/
#header .row-1 {
 height:110px;
 background:#0d0d0d;
}
 #header .row-1 .logo {
  position:relative;
  margin-right: 55px;
  padding:0px 0 0 0;
  float:left;
 }
 #header .nav {
  float:right;
 }
  #header .nav li {
  }
   #header .nav li a {
    color:#727171;
    text-decoration:none;
    
   }
   #header .nav li a:hover, #header .nav li a.current {
    color:#fff;
   }

Comment: @user1519929, From next time, update the code, in your original question.

Answer (score 6):

By Using `position:absolute` on specific element you can achieve it.

Example:

```
 .chat{
     position:absolute;
     right: 0px;
     z-index: 9999;
     width: xyz;
     height: xyz;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey now you can used to position  as like this

your main menu div id give to position relative

and give to chat id position absolute as like this

**css**

```
    .nav{
    position:relative;
    }


.chat{
position:absolute;
right:-20px;
z-index:999;
width:xxx;
height:xxx;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav">

<div class="chat">
// your chat code here 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: I've tried position absolute, when i resize the browser the element does not stay in place, instead if increases the page width by 1000px and i have to scroll to an empty/grey area to see the element.

Comment: Hi now check to this live demo http://tinkerbin.com/qkGYSEOa  now just change to position relative into absolute of chat and cut to your chat code and page after ul ended and give to .dark class position relative ..... http://tinkerbin.com/IpYEyzyQ

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact code i think somebody like that would work:

Set the outer container to a relative position. Now you can insert a item with a absolute Button in it wich is over all other items without moving them.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the z-index of that element and that way it will be above the other layers in  your page and it will be able to move freely over the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting it above the menu, and then using a negative margin on the menu.